# Is there a way to stop IE10/IE11 from showing open or save prompt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, blob, internet-explorer-11

I am downloading files from server using javascript blob something like

```
let blob = new Blob([resposne['_body']], { type: contentType });
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName); // in case of IE
} else {
    let objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}
```

The code above works fine but in IE it shows a dialog:

[image: prompt]

Also if I put a direct pdf link in the href tag then it also works fine. So it looks like there is no problem with the adobe plugin.

What I want is to directly open the file instead of showing this prompt. I tried [Registry hack as suggested here](http://9to5it.com/internet-explorer-disable-do-you-want-to-open-or-save-this-file-prompt/) but did not have any luck. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who is facing the same issue, I solved it by using `window.open`. Instead of downloading the response, I directly pass the URL to `window.open` something like

```
window.open(apiUrl) // Exmp "host:api/documents/download?id=1"
```

Note:-API should returns the stream response with header type set. In my case C# web API method was

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download(int id)
{
   var data = _service.Download(id);
   HttpResponseMessage result = null;
   result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(data);//here data is byte[]
   var name = data.Name.ToLower().Contains(data.DocType.ToLower())
            ? data.Name
            : $"{data.Name}{data.DocType}";
   result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline")
   {
            FileName = name
   };
   result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(name));
//here i am setting up the headers content type for example 'text/application-json'
   return result;
}
```

Hope it will help someone.